# Amount of numbers on both sides of 1

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Let's take the interval $[0,10]$.

> Are the same 'amount' of numbers on both sides of 1?

I'm getting confused, 'cause they differ by the packing density.

Comment: Your question is ill-defined.

Comment: Amount as in cardinality: yes. Amount as in measure: no.

Comment: @KennyLau Probably each question is ill-defined, 'cause we don't know all the boundary conditions:-) It means that I may have had no idea what I was asking for or I didn't know what to take into account.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  Please, would you like to elaborate more on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of *cardinality*, there are an equal number of numbers on both sides of 1 in $[0,10]$ because there is a bijection between the two sides. One such bijection is given below.
$$f:[0,1)\mapsto(1,10],f(x)=10-9x$$
In terms of (Lebesgue) *measure*, however, the two sides are not equal: one has measure 1 and the other 9.

Comment: I'm right in my understanding: It's like 1 elephant is like 1 ant in terms of completedness or rather unity, but taking into account their weight, they're not the same. (?)

Comment: @Lili Something like that. "Weight" is measure and "unity" is cardinality.

Comment: @Lili More specifically, there are two main kinds of infinite sets: the natural numbers and the real numbers. The naturals are countable and the reals are uncountable. The intervals above are uncountable because they are over the real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For every number 'left' of $1$, there is a number 'right' of $1$ if you take mapping $x \in [0,1] \mapsto 1+9x$. This mapping is obviously a bijection.

Comment: Yeah, this is how I thought, but 'visibly' they are less numbers on the left of 1 than on the right side.

Comment: Well, it gets worse ;) There are an equal amount of numbers in the $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: I guess this is the case, when common-sense intuition fails :)